# Why would C-3PO consider the Millennium Falcon to be old?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-motivation, millennium-falcon

In both Legends AND the new Disney canon, the original components of [**C-3PO**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-3PO) (his droid brain, frame, etc.) were nearly 100 years old by the time Anakin Skywalker found him prior to Episode I. The [**Millennium Falcon**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon), on the other hand, was constructed nearly 60 years later. In Legends continuity, the origins of both droid and ship were known prior to the reboot despite C-3PO having his mind wiped in Episode III. In Legends, there are several cases where the droid wonders why Han even bothers with the Falcon instead of simply replacing it with a newer model. Not sure if this still occurs in the new EU - I'm a little behind on that one.

**Why would C-3PO agree with other characters that the ship - which is 50 years younger then him - to be "old", "ancient", or "obsolete" as is often mentioned?**

I'll accept an answer from either continuity if appropriate.

Comment: I have no canonical basis for any of this, but: 1) Different tech has different lifespans, and this reflects how people talk and think about it. (My phone is incredibly ancient. I recently rented a rather modern-feeling house. The house is three years older than the phone.) 2) Even if Threepio's components are old, his memory has been erased, so his sense of self might not be...

Comment: Do you have specific quotes for context?. Just because thing A is twice as old as thing B, that doesn't make thing B not old. C-3PO could simply be meaning "the falcon is pretty old and obsolete, relative to other ships around" and not "the falcon is pretty old and obsolete compared to me".

Comment: That ship was used by: gamblers, smugglers, darth waders death squadron, pirates, jedi, ... and has been in destruction of death star, had many modifications, shes not pretty but shes tough. Like old battle components, has seen too much, old.

Comment: During the prequels, 3PO also believes that Anakin was his maker, though we know that his parts originated elsewhere. Since we know he had his memory wiped at the end of Ep3, it's possible/likely that he has no idea how old he really is anymore. For all we know for sure, 3PO believes he came online in 19BBY.

Comment: Threepio behaves like a person with low self-esteem: he is defensive of himself, speaks highly of his own talents, and is quick to criticize others.  He may be so concerned with his own limitations that he transfers those insecurities to others.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly I think that C3PO sees the ship old by its data in memory, that is, its data on the Millennium Falcon make it a simple light freighter YT-1300 standard.

If you compare this ship with its origins you see that (although it is old) much of its equipment has been renovated. The changes to be highlighted in the millennial Halcon are:

**Hyperdrive:** The hyperdrive system aboard the Hawk was twice as large as that of a standard YT-1300 freighter.

**Navigation computer:** Better than other ships, with a greater capacity of calculation that allowed this ship to be faster in the calculation of distances.

**Arakyd ST2 impact missile:** These missiles were incorporated by Han to the ship, since this ship did not have missile launchers.

**Light turbolaseres:** These lasers were added to allow the Halcon to be equipped with greater fire capacity.

I doubt that C-3PO, knew of the existence of all these modifications when he says that he sees "old" this ship, since he would refer to a standard model of said ship that obviously was obsolete. It is only necessary to see some of its characteristics such as the material of the ship, if you compare it with those of the Wings-X or Wings-Y much more updated, you will see this diference because it is "old" materials.

If you want more information, Source (books,documentary film and links):

- Starships of the Galaxy (2007)
- Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection
- "Secrets of the Falcon"
- Rebel Alliance Sourcebook
- [Star Wars Databank](Http://www.starwars.com/databank/millennium-falcon?_ga=1.199827246.1675632785.1447746614)

**PS:** *It is seen in both the cinema and the animated series that the droids need updates, apart from that to get concrete data on the systems of a ship have to connect to it.*